# When to use data binding of AngularJS and when of Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Rails and AngularJS seems to be a good match. I am, however, greatly confused with respect to data binding. AngularJS provides data through a scope and on that basis it generates content.

But coming from Rails I only know the case where the data is provided through Rails (as in my case) and then put into the view through the template language (erb). So while I want to make my web application responsive and offer dynamic features I don't see how to connect these two concepts.

Should I simply fetch data from AngularJS through AJAX requests to fill the data scope? What is the general approach here and when should one use the data binding through Rails (ERB templates) and when through AngularJS (`{{ data.cookie }}`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possible combination. You can use ERB template and let angularJS controls only part of the DOM... but this is absolutely NOT an elegant way.

AngularJS has its own templating system, so it should control the whole view : you can forget ERB if you are working with Rails + AngularJS. Yes, you should definetely fetch data from AngularJS through AJAX requests to fill the data scope. AngularJS has built-in solution to handle communication with server.

As you can notice, AngularJS is a full standalone front-end framework : it can walk by his own. So the elegant way is AngularJS <-> REST <-> Rails.

Comment: Thanks, your post made it clear. It's kind of obvious, but I missed the last connection!

Comment: @davidb583 "AngularJS has built-in solution to handle communication with server"

Are you talking about json api, or do you mean 3 way data binding with the database? Either way, can you point us to a specific place? thanks

Comment: @gwho here is the official doc for http, it can handle any kind of request since it is not opinionated :  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1):

Make an api scope in your routes where you can get data for Angular. 
Forget the combination of Rails and Views when you're working with those two technologies.
Angular will now handle your views.

Here's a little tutorial combining those two technologies, I think it will help you to understand it : [Tutorial](http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/04/22/angularjs-on-rails-4-part-1/)

Comment: Wish I knew this earlier.